# MySQL use JOIN or store directly

Tags: php, mysql, performance, join, database-schema

I have tables `users` and `posts`. Table `users` have columns `user_id` and `username`, and table `posts` have columns `post_id` and `user_id`.

When I'm getting posts I also want to get username, so is it better to use JOIN between tables `users` and `posts` to get username, or to store username also in table `posts`?

How JOIN affects on performance, assuming you have more few million rows in `posts` and `users` tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted practice is to utilize the JOIN statement and not have username within the posts table. To do so would violate normal form and result in redundant data. Also - what happens if the username changes? Then you have two tables (users, posts) that no longer match up because there would be records where user_id would not match up with username. Just some things to consider.

Answer (score 1):

That's why we have RDMS, few million rows are not a big deal for MySQL. If you think about keeping username in post data you should think about NoSQL databases.

Comment: if you add some data on join vs other approach, could become a good answer